# StreamingFileSink bulk writer results in some checkpoint error when running in AWS EMR

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

Unable to use StreamingFileSink and store incoming events in compressed fashion.

I am trying to use StreamingFileSink to write unbounded event stream to S3. In the process, I would like to compress the data to make better use of storage size available.

I wrote a compressed string writer, by borrowing some code from `SequenceFileWriterFactory` from flink. It fails with the exception I described below.

If I try to use `BucketingSink`, it works great.
Using BucketingSink, I approached compressed string write as below. Again, I borrowed this code from some other pull request.

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.StreamWriterBase;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Compressor;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CompressionStringWriter<T> extends StreamWriterBase<T> implements Writer<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3231207311080446279L;

    private String codecName;

    private String separator;

    public String getCodecName() {
        return codecName;
    }

    public String getSeparator() {
        return separator;
    }

    private transient CompressionOutputStream compressedOutputStream;

    public CompressionStringWriter(String codecName, String separator) {
        this.codecName = codecName;
        this.separator = separator;
    }

    public CompressionStringWriter(String codecName) {
        this(codecName, System.lineSeparator());
    }

    protected CompressionStringWriter(CompressionStringWriter<T> other) {
        super(other);
        this.codecName = other.codecName;
        this.separator = other.separator;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(FileSystem fs, Path path) throws IOException {
        super.open(fs, path);
        Configuration conf = fs.getConf();
        CompressionCodecFactory codecFactory = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
        CompressionCodec codec = codecFactory.getCodecByName(codecName);
        if (codec == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Codec " + codecName + " not found");
        }
        Compressor compressor = CodecPool.getCompressor(codec, conf);
        compressedOutputStream = codec.createOutputStream(getStream(), compressor);

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (compressedOutputStream != null) {
            compressedOutputStream.close();
            compressedOutputStream = null;
        } else {
            super.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Object element) throws IOException {
        getStream();
        compressedOutputStream.write(element.toString().getBytes());
        compressedOutputStream.write(this.separator.getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public CompressionStringWriter<T> duplicate() {
        return new CompressionStringWriter<>(this);
    }
}
```

```
BucketingSink<DeviceEvent> bucketingSink = new BucketingSink<>("s3://"+ this.bucketName + "/" + this.objectPrefix);
        bucketingSink
                .setBucketer(new OrgIdBasedBucketAssigner())
                .setWriter(new CompressionStringWriter<DeviceEvent>("Gzip", "\n"))
                .setPartPrefix("file-")
                .setPartSuffix(".gz")
                .setBatchSize(1_500_000);
```

The one with `BucketingSink` works.

Now my code snippets using StreamingFileSink involves the below set of code.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.BulkWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CompressedStringBulkWriter<T> implements BulkWriter<T> {

    private final CompressedStringWriter compressedStringWriter;

    public CompressedStringBulkWriter(final CompressedStringWriter compressedStringWriter) {
        this.compressedStringWriter = compressedStringWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void addElement(T element) throws IOException {
        this.compressedStringWriter.write(element);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        this.compressedStringWriter.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() throws IOException {
        this.compressedStringWriter.close();
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.BulkWriter;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CompressedStringBulkWriterFactory<T> implements BulkWriter.Factory<T> {

    private SerializableHadoopConfiguration serializableHadoopConfiguration;

    public CompressedStringBulkWriterFactory(final Configuration hadoopConfiguration) {
        this.serializableHadoopConfiguration = new SerializableHadoopConfiguration(hadoopConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public BulkWriter<T> create(FSDataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        return new CompressedStringBulkWriter(new CompressedStringWriter(out, serializableHadoopConfiguration.get(), "Gzip", "\n"));
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem;
import org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Compressor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CompressedStringWriter<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompressedStringWriter.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2115292142239557448L;


    private String separator;

    private transient CompressionOutputStream compressedOutputStream;

    public CompressedStringWriter(FSDataOutputStream out, Configuration hadoopConfiguration, String codecName, String separator) {
        this.separator = separator;
        try {
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(hadoopConfiguration, "Unable to determine hadoop configuration using path");
            CompressionCodecFactory codecFactory = new CompressionCodecFactory(hadoopConfiguration);
            CompressionCodec codec = codecFactory.getCodecByName(codecName);
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(codec, "Codec " + codecName + " not found");
            LOG.info("The codec name that was loaded from hadoop {}", codec);
            Compressor compressor = CodecPool.getCompressor(codec, hadoopConfiguration);
            this.compressedOutputStream = codec.createOutputStream(out, compressor);
            LOG.info("Setup a compressor for codec {} and compressor {}", codec, compressor);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to compose a hadoop compressor for the path", ex);
        }
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (compressedOutputStream != null) {
            compressedOutputStream.flush();
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (compressedOutputStream != null) {
            compressedOutputStream.close();
            compressedOutputStream = null;
        }
    }

    public void write(T element) throws IOException {
        compressedOutputStream.write(element.toString().getBytes());
        compressedOutputStream.write(this.separator.getBytes());
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableHadoopConfiguration implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1960900291123078166L;

    private transient Configuration hadoopConfig;

    SerializableHadoopConfiguration(Configuration hadoopConfig) {
        this.hadoopConfig = hadoopConfig;
    }

    Configuration get() {
        return this.hadoopConfig;
    }

    // --------------------
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        this.hadoopConfig.write(out);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException {
        final Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.readFields(in);

        if (this.hadoopConfig == null) {
            this.hadoopConfig = config;
        }
    }
}
```

My actual flink job

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties kinesisConsumerConfig = new Properties();
...
...
DataStream<DeviceEvent> kinesis =
                env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(this.streamName, new DeviceEventSchema(), kinesisConsumerConfig)).name("source")
                .setParallelism(16)
                .setMaxParallelism(24);

final StreamingFileSink<DeviceEvent> bulkCompressStreamingFileSink = StreamingFileSink.<DeviceEvent>forBulkFormat(
                path,
                new CompressedStringBulkWriterFactory<>(
                        BucketingSink.createHadoopFileSystem(
                                new Path("s3a://"+ this.bucketName + "/" + this.objectPrefix),
                                null).getConf()))
                .withBucketAssigner(new OrgIdBucketAssigner())
                .build();

deviceEventDataStream.addSink(bulkCompressStreamingFileSink).name("bulkCompressStreamingFileSink").setParallelism(16);

env.execute();
```

I expect data to be saved in S3 as multiple files. Unfortunately no files are being created.

In the logs, I see below exception

```
2019-05-15 22:17:20,855 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Sink: bulkCompressStreamingFileSink (11/16) (c73684c10bb799a6e0217b6795571e22) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.Exception: Could not perform checkpoint 1 for operator Sink: bulkCompressStreamingFileSink (11/16).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpointOnBarrier(StreamTask.java:595)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer.notifyCheckpoint(BarrierBuffer.java:396)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer.processBarrier(BarrierBuffer.java:292)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer.getNextNonBlocked(BarrierBuffer.java:200)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:209)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not complete snapshot 1 for operator Sink: bulkCompressStreamingFileSink (11/16).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:422)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.checkpointStreamOperator(StreamTask.java:1113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.executeCheckpointing(StreamTask.java:1055)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.checkpointState(StreamTask.java:729)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpointOnBarrier(StreamTask.java:586)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedFile.requireOpened(RefCountedFile.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedFile.write(RefCountedFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedBufferingFileStream.flush(RefCountedBufferingFileStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.closeAndUploadPart(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.closeForCommit(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.PartFileWriter.closeForCommit(PartFileWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkPartWriter.closeForCommit(BulkPartWriter.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.closePartFile(Bucket.java:239)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.prepareBucketForCheckpointing(Bucket.java:280)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.onReceptionOfCheckpoint(Bucket.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotActiveBuckets(Buckets.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.snapshotState(Buckets.java:235)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.snapshotState(StreamingFileSink.java:347)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.trySnapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.snapshotFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:395)
```

So wondering, what am I missing.

I am using AWS EMR latest (5.23).

Answer (score 0):

In `CompressedStringBulkWriter#close()`, you are calling the `close()` method on the `CompressionCodecStream` which also closes the underlying the stream i.e. Flink's `FSDataOutputStream`. It has to be opened for the checkpointing to be done properly by Flink's internal to guarantee recoverable stream. That is why you are getting

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedFile.requireOpened(RefCountedFile.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedFile.write(RefCountedFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.utils.RefCountedBufferingFileStream.flush(RefCountedBufferingFileStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.closeAndUploadPart(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:199)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.closeForCommit(S3RecoverableFsDataOutputStream.java:166)
```

So instead of `compressedOutputStream.close()`, use `compressedOutputStream.finish()` which just flushes everything that's in buffer to the outputstream without closing it. BTW, there is an inbuilt HadoopCompressionBulkWriter made available in the latest version Flink, you can also use that.